# Zurb Foundation Rails Topbar Nav black highlighting when hovering over nav link

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, navigation, zurb-foundation

I'm having an issue with Zurb Foundation where hovering over the top navbar links highlights the menu in black by default.

This is fine when using the default menu color #111, but is problematic when using other colors.

What I want to do is prevent any highlighting at all. I don't want the colors to change at all when hovering over the menu.

I have researched this problem for the past few days and have tried numerous changes in the files to no avail.

I am new to coding and any help would be very welcome.

To give an example of what I'm describing, here is a link to the Heroku deployment of a app I threw together very quickly to introduce my bro-in-law to Rails so that he might consider learning it:

http://vast-headland-1673.herokuapp.com/

That Heroku deployment illustrates what I'm describing when you hover over the menu items on the top bar nav.

Here is a link to the github repository:

https://github.com/marcacyr/Fernando-s-Sample-App

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the colors to change at all when hovering over the menu.
See this style hover on your tobar

```
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
background: #000;
}

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
background: #000;
}

.top-bar-section ul li>a:hover {
background: #2b2b2b;
}

.top-bar-section ul li>a:hover {
background: #2b2b2b;
}
```

You can change `background:#000` and `background:#2b2b2b` to `background:#3b5999`, add one css file (e.g `a.css`), and put this :

```
/* for dropdown */
.top-bar-section ul li.has-dropdown ul li>a:hover {
background: #4264ab;
}

/* for topbar */
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
background: #3b5999;
}

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
background: #3b5999;
}

.top-bar-section ul li>a:hover {
background: #3b5999;
}

.top-bar-section ul li>a:hover {
background: #3b5999;
}
```

And on your `layouts/application.html` call a.css looks like

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", "a" %>
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, and there is still no change.. I have tried to explore the possibility that there is something conflicting elsewhere in the stylesheets assets.. but I haven't found anything yet. Do you have any suggestions of where else I might look?

Thank you anonymousxxx

Comment: @marcacyr : updated answer, I have try to clone your application and I added one css file for override some style from zurb foundation.

Comment: I have this issue as well and tried this but cannot seem to get it to work. I'm sure that I mixed something up. I am actually ok with the highlight but would love darken($topbar-bg, 10%);. Any other suggestions? I have been at this for weeks. Thanks

Comment: @Patrick Sorry too late, I have give an answer on your question.